# Error with setWidth in android

Tags: android, textview, width, offsetwidth

My problem is that i want change width of my TEXTVIEW (INPUT TEXT).
In emulator that code work success but when i try to work with my app in mobile that crash it.

My answer is: Why my app crash when i try to change .setWidth? and how can i solve my problem?

A lot of thanks.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.binomial);

    EditText TextVA, TextVB, TextVC, EtiquetaA, EtiquetaB, EtiquetaC;

    TextVA = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextP);
    TextVB = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextK);
    TextVC = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    ArrayList<TextView> listaTexto = new ArrayList<TextView>();
    listaTexto.add(TextVA);
    listaTexto.add(TextVB);
    listaTexto.add(TextVC);

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int y = size.y;
    int x = size.x;

    ResolucionPantalla respant = new ResolucionPantalla(y, x);

    for (int i=0;i<listaTexto.size();i++)
            //ResolInput METHOD return size in px according to the screen size
        listaTexto.get(i).setWidth(respant.ResolInput());

    Button BotonCalcular = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCalcular);
    BotonCalcular.setOnClickListener(this);       
}
```

EDIT: TextView to EditText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several potential issues...

For starters:

```
TextVA = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editTextP);
```

Is `R.id.editTextP` an `EditText`?  You are casting it as a `TextView`

And also:

Calling `setWidth` here will have no effect.  There is an `onLayout` method for each view that gets called after `onCreate` is finished.  The width/height get set to whatever is specified in your XML layout during that call

You can either extend and create your own `EditText` and override the `onLayout` method, or you can figure out how to size your views correctly via XML.